# Como Convertir ICollection<t1> en ICollection<t2>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Tengo una Consulta LinQ To Entities,

Y me retorna un ActivityModel, Pero verdaderamente hace la consulta a la entidad Actividad, y asigno cada dato como lo pueden ver, pero me trae las Ordenes como `Icollection<Orden>`, y en ActivityModel Lo tengo como `ICollection<OrdenModel>`
Que puedo hacer para convertirlo?, con la mejor practica posible, y si pueden mejorar el código estaría bien muchas gracias!

```
var result = (from a in ctx.Actividad
                          join e in ctx.Empleado on a.IdEmpleado equals e.IdEmpleado
                          where a.IdEstimacion == id
                          select new ActivityModel()
                          {
                              Responsable = e.Nombre,
                              IdEmpleado = a.IdEmpleado,
                              IdActividad = a.IdActividad,
                              IdEstimacion = a.IdEstimacion,
                              OrdenModels = a.Ordenes,
                              Nombre = a.Nombre,
                              FechaFinal = a.FechaFinal,
                              FechaInicial = a.FechaInicial,
                              HorasPresupuestadas = a.HorasPresupuestadas
                          }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede utilizar *automappers*! https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2/Pages/2. 
Esto para mapear la entidad que quieres.

Lo que podrías hacer es una función que retorne esa colección, y dentro de la función utilizar *automappers*. Es fácil de usar y te ahorra mucho código.

Comment: Pues lo intente, pero no logro hacerlo, cual es tu idea ? En código por supuesto

Answer (score 0):

Creo que si haces:

```
var collection = Collection<OrdenModel>
select new ActivityModel()
{
    Responsable = e.Nombre,
    IdEmpleado = a.IdEmpleado,
    IdActividad = a.IdActividad,
    IdEstimacion = a.IdEstimacion,
    OrdenModels = collection.add
    (
        new OrdenModel{ prop1 = a.value. prop2 = a.value2}
    ),
    Nombre = a.Nombre,
    FechaFinal = a.FechaFinal,
    FechaInicial = a.FechaInicial,
    HorasPresupuestadas = a.HorasPresupuestadas
}).ToList();
```

No he probado el código, pero si las propiedades son similares, que las puedas mapear, entonces será sencillo, pues cuando acabe la interacción ya tendrás asociada a la colección *OrdenModels*, los valores que necesitas.